# How to create admin menu item in wordpress to insert info into theme file

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to integrate a comments policy section on my website. I currently manually entered in by adding some php code on comments.php in my child theme.
 However, What I would like to accomplish is to create an admin menu item that allows me to change the message in the admin menu any time i need to make changes to the comment policy.

I am guessing there should be a way to have a form on an admin menu page to fill out that will define a param, then in `comments.php` call that param to echo on the page.

Am I correct? How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

You first have to add your option field with [add_settings_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_settings_field/)

Then you have to register it with [register_setting](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/)

Then in `comments.php` you can use `get_option` to get the value of your field